# JMeter API Load Testing - 404 Response code = test failed?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

Just need a clarification here, I'm doing API testing on a sample REST web services. If the response code is 404, does the test will returns 100% error too?

[image]

FYI no body data is input here. I also add response code assertion below the HTTP request but I don't think this is related to the error.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean it can be change? how to change? any configuration?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Response Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) above 399 as failed

If you're receiving [HTTP Status Code 404](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) - JMeter will mark the request as failed.

If you **expect** certain request to return HTTP Status Code 404 and would like JMeter to not to fail that particular request(s) - you can add a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of this request and configure it like:

[image]

This way JMeter will expect that the request will return 404 and won't fail the sampler

[image]

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps)